# boolean indexing that can produce a view to a large pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

Got a large dataframe that I want to take slices of (according to multiple boolean criteria), and then modify the entries in those slices in order to change the original dataframe -- i.e. I need a `view` to the original. Problem is, fancy indexing always returns a `copy`. Thought of the `.ix` method, but boolean indexing with the `df.ix[]` method also returns a copy.

Essentially if `df` is my dataframe, I'd like a view to column C such that `C!=0, A==10, B<30,...` etc. Is there a fast way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though `df.loc[idx]` may be a copy of a portion of `df`, [**assignment** to `df.loc[idx]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail) modifies `df` itself. (This is also true of `df.iloc` and `df.ix`.)

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[9,10]*6,
                   'B':range(23,35),
                   'C':range(-6,6)})

print(df)
#      A   B  C
# 0    9  23 -6
# 1   10  24 -5
# 2    9  25 -4
# 3   10  26 -3
# 4    9  27 -2
# 5   10  28 -1
# 6    9  29  0
# 7   10  30  1
# 8    9  31  2
# 9   10  32  3
# 10   9  33  4
# 11  10  34  5
```

Here is our boolean index:

```
idx = (df['C']!=0) & (df['A']==10) & (df['B']<30)
```

We can modify those rows of `df` where `idx` is True by assigning to `df.loc[idx, ...]`. For example,

```
df.loc[idx, 'A'] += df.loc[idx, 'B'] * df.loc[idx, 'C']
print(df)
```

yields

```
      A   B  C
0     9  23 -6
1  -110  24 -5
2     9  25 -4
3   -68  26 -3
4     9  27 -2
5   -18  28 -1
6     9  29  0
7    10  30  1
8     9  31  2
9    10  32  3
10    9  33  4
11   10  34  5
```

Comment: When I run the command `subdf['A'] += subdf['B'] * subdf['C']`, it does change the values but I get the following warning: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter`.  I then tried following the recommendation in this warning `subdf.loc[:,'A'] += subdf['B'] * subdf['C']` and get the same warning again.  What is correct?

Comment: @stvn66: The warning is saying that `subdf` is a copy of a slice of `df`, and assigning new values to a copy of a slice is often not desireable. For example, if one were to use `df[idx]['A'] += df[idx]['B'] + df[idx]['C']` then `df` itself would not change because only `df[idx]` is modified and `df[idx]` is a *copy* of a slice of `df`. Modifying the copy does not modify the original.  In this case, we assigned `subdf` to the copy and we *want* to modify
`subdf`. So the code is doing what we want and the warning is overzealous. 
So you are free to ignore the warning.

Comment: @stvn66: If you don't like seeing a warning, you could use `subdf = df[idx].copy()`. Then `subdf['A'] += subdf['B'] * subdf['C']` will not raise a warning. This does however perform an unnecessary copy. Therefore another alternative is to turn off the warning with `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`.

Comment: @stvn66: Yet another option is to suppress the warning on a per-instance basis with [`with warnings.catch_warnings()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings).

Comment: @stvn66: If you wish to modify `df`, then you would use `df.loc[idx, 'A'] += df.loc[idx, 'B'] + df.loc[idx, 'C']`. Assigning to `df.loc[idx, 'A']` succeeds in modifying `df`, whereas assigning to `df[idx]['A']` does not. Be sure to read http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail to fully understand this issue.

Comment: @stvn66: After re-reading the question, I see the ultimate goal is simply to modify `df`. So the answer is to assign to `df.loc` as in  `df.loc[idx, 'A'] += df.loc[idx, 'B'] * df.loc[idx, 'C']`. I've edited my answer to reflect this; my original answer is obsolete.

Comment: I appreciated learning about the `df.update` method you originally used but this updated version does not produce the warning that the other method did.

Answer (score 6):

The pandas docs have a section on [Returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy):

> The rules about when a view on the data is returned are entirely dependent on NumPy. **Whenever an array of labels or a boolean vector are involved in the indexing operation, the result will be a copy.** With single label / scalar indexing and slicing, e.g. `df.ix[3:6]` or `df.ix[:, 'A']`, a view will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of unutbu's example you could also use the boolean index on df.index like so:

```
In [11]: df.ix[df.index[idx]] = 999

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
      A    B    C
0     9   23   -6
1   999  999  999
2     9   25   -4
3   999  999  999
4     9   27   -2
5   999  999  999
6     9   29    0
7    10   30    1
8     9   31    2
9    10   32    3
10    9   33    4
11   10   34    5
```