# What is the correct syntax for using logical or boolean indexing with Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I want to use logical indexing to modify values in a Pandas DataFrame (version 0.15.2) as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15144847/3585557).  I keep getting the following warnings:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item_labels[indexer[info_axis]]] = value
```

Here is an example to demonstrate.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[9,10]*6,
                   'B':range(23,35),
                   'C':range(-6,6)})

print df
     A   B  C
0    9  23 -6
1   10  24 -5
2    9  25 -4
3   10  26 -3
4    9  27 -2
5   10  28 -1
6    9  29  0
7   10  30  1
8    9  31  2
9   10  32  3
10   9  33  4
11  10  34  5
```

What is the correct way to use logical indexing for changing values? Say I want to subtract 10 from all the values in the `B` column that are > 30, why is the following not preferred? I realize this is chained assignment and is discouraged.  In the code I am actually using it actually does do what I intended (it is NOT making a copy but actually editing the original DataFrame) but it still displays the warning:

```
df['B-type'] = 'B'                  # create column with dummy values
df['B-type'][df['B'] > 30] = 'BI'   # populate the column with real values for BI type
df['B-type'][df['B'] <= 30] = 'BII' # populate the column with real values for BII type
print df
     A   B  C B-type
0    9  23 -6    BII
1   10  24 -5    BII
2    9  25 -4    BII
3   10  26 -3    BII
4    9  27 -2    BII
5   10  28 -1    BII
6    9  29  0    BII
7   10  30  1    BII
8    9  31  2     BI
9   10  32  3     BI
10   9  33  4     BI
11  10  34  5     BI
```

It is not clear why this is "wrong" but still works fine.

Comment: I noticed when the warning occurs is not consistent.  As pointed out `df[df['B'] > 30]['B'] = ...` clearly makes a copy but I checked the code I have this issue with and the order of the chained assignment is the other way around and still produces the warning, `df['B'][df['B'] > 30] = ...`, but it is not making a copy and it does produce the desired result.  I just updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use [`.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) like below -

```
df.loc[df['B'] > 30,'B'] = df.loc[df['B'] > 30,'B'] - 10
```

Demo -

```
In [9]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[9,10]*6,
   ...:                    'B':range(23,35),
   ...:                    'C':range(-6,6)})

In [10]:

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
     A   B  C
0    9  23 -6
1   10  24 -5
2    9  25 -4
3   10  26 -3
4    9  27 -2
5   10  28 -1
6    9  29  0
7   10  30  1
8    9  31  2
9   10  32  3
10   9  33  4
11  10  34  5

In [11]: df.loc[df['B'] > 30,'B'] = df.loc[df['B'] > 30,'B'] - 10

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
     A   B  C
0    9  23 -6
1   10  24 -5
2    9  25 -4
3   10  26 -3
4    9  27 -2
5   10  28 -1
6    9  29  0
7   10  30  1
8    9  21  2
9   10  22  3
10   9  23  4
11  10  24  5
```

---

Or as stated in the comment you can also use the *augmented assignment* version of the above -

```
df.loc[df['B'] > 30,'B'] -= 10
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the following to simplify the expression: `df.loc[df['B'] > 30,'B'] -= 10`?

Comment: Not that i can think of.

Answer (score 2):

This way of accessing is called chained assignment and should be avoided as mentioned in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). The reason it does not work as intended is that a *copy*, instead of a *view*, of the DataFrame is updated. This means that the original DataFrame is left unmodified.

Consider this chained assignment:

```
df[df['B'] > 30]['B'] = -999
```

It is equivalent to the following:

```
df_something = df[df['B'] > 30]
df_something['B'] = -999

>>> print df
     A   B  C
0    9  23 -6
1   10  24 -5
2    9  25 -4
3   10  26 -3
4    9  27 -2
5   10  28 -1
6    9  29  0
7   10  30  1
8    9  31  2
9   10  32  3
10   9  33  4
11  10  34  5

>>> print df_something
     A    B  C
8    9 -999  2
9   10 -999  3
10   9 -999  4
11  10 -999  5
```

It can be seen that indeed a copy is created and updated, which is what the warning is about. The correct way performing such assignment is to avoid chaining, i.e. through only a single operation using an appropriate indexer:

```
df.loc[df['B'] > 30, 'B'] = -999
```

Note that this is different from `df.loc[df['B'] > 30]['B'] = -999` which is also a chained assignment.